# IF cell is blank then move to cell another cell, otherwise TODAY()-cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet where I need to calculate how many days it has been since the day that is already in a cell, for example if h2 has has 10/10/18 then I need to calculate how long its been until today, which I have achieved via = TODAY()-cellname. However, some cells are empty so if cell h3 is empty and doesn't have a date I want it to go to cell e3 and calculate how many days, and if e3 is empty then it reads from b3 but if h3 isn't empty I want to to read the date in h3 and give me a result

How would I go about that?

In the picture it shows each service with the how many days column, but I don't want each service to have a how many days column, I just want one how many days column at the end.

[image]

Comment: What does "I want it to go to cell e3" mean? Perhaps it would be helpful for you to show a table with the results you want so we can see what you're after.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In J2 something like

```
=IFERROR(TODAY()-IF(ISBLANK(H2),IF(ISBLANK(E2),IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",B2),E2),H2),"")
```